# Pygame Zero Player Animation Code Is Not Working

Tags: python, pgzero

I have been trying to code a small game with a character that moves around. For some reason, I can't use gifs. After that, I turned the gif into a bunch of pngs and with that, I tried to write some code to animate it:

```
def animate():
    global frame
    curr_img = "player-walk" + str(frame)
    player.image = curr_img
    frame += 1
    if frame > 2:
        frame = 1
```

When I tried this code, I would get an error as soon as I called it. Here is the full code that I wrote:

```
import pgzrun as pgzero
import pygame

player = Actor("player")
frame = 1

WIDTH = 660
HEIGHT = 450

def move_player():
    if keyboard.w:
        player.y -= 2
        clock.schedule_interval(animate(), 0.5)
    if keyboard.s:
        player.y += 2
    if keyboard.a:
        player.x -= 2
    if keyboard.d:
        player.x += 2

def animate():
    global frame
    curr_img = "player-walk" + str(frame)
    player.image = curr_img
    frame += 1
    if frame > 2:
        frame = 1

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    player.draw()

def update():
    move_player()

pgzero.go()
```

Error is in this link:
mystb.in/LitFillEquilibrium.sql

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I put the error in this link: https://mystb.in/LitFillEquilibrium.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

`clock.schedule_interval(animate(), 0.5)`

`clock.schedule_interval` takes in a callable(a function) and the interval. By adding parentheses after `animate`, you're actually calling the function and passing its output. Since `animate` doesn't return anything(`None`), you're doing the same as this:

`clock.schedule_interval(None, 0.5)`

where it should be

`clock.schedule_interval(animate, 0.5)`

Comment: OMG Thanks! I really needed to know this and now it works!!!! Thank you so much!